# What's the most efficient way to run through keywords/functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I'm working on a terminal application written in **python 3.7**. Currently, when a command is inputted, it is passed through a function that looks like this:

```py
def execute(command):
    if command is None or command.isspace() or command == "":
        terminal()

    command = command.split(" ")
    command = list(command)
    command[0] = command[0].lower()

    var(command)
    iftrue(command)
    ... etc
```

and each function looks like this:

```py
def func(command):
    if command[0] == "func":
        function code blah blah blah
```

I haven't tried other methods as I am unsure what to use - and I'm using this method because I saw a piece of code that used it a long time ago.

What would be the best **(most efficient/optimised)** way to do this? This seems very wasteful and slow and with more functions, ones lower down the list could take noticeable time to be reached.

Comment: You should probably use a dedicated module for these tasks, like `argparse` or `cmd`

Comment: @DeepSpace can you elaborate?

Comment: Do some research on these modules, you'll find much more information than I can fit in a comment/answer https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html  and https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cmd.html

Comment: ...I just add to @DeepSpace list of modules some 3rd-party ones: `click`, `invoke`, `docopt`

Comment: for what it's worth, I use `click` to great effect at work.

Comment: Are you seriously asking about a few microseconds more or less that it would take to reach a function at the end of your “if” chain? Even if you had 20000 “if” conditions I doubt you would notice any difference whatsoever, unless you’re running a Commodore 64 type of machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary where the command-strings are the keys and the functions are the values. Dictionary will have a log(n) search time, and should keep the tree structure balanced. So having `d` as the `dict`, defined similar to this:

```
d = {'func1': myFunc1, 'func2': MyFunc2...}
```

And of course:

```
def myFunc1(args..):
    ...

def myFunc2(args..):
    ...
```

We end up with:

```
if cmd in d:
    d[cmd](args...)
```

Comment: "Dictionary will have a log(n) search time" Maybe in very rare cases of a lot of hash collisions... other than that dictionaries have O(1) lookup

Comment: I ended up using this method. Works brilliantly